# micronaut managing session with vue

Tags: micronaut

EDIT: How can I manage a session with vue.js and micronaut?

When using micronaut `security-session` with the following configuration:

```
  security:
    enabled: true
    endpoints:
      login:
        enabled: true
      logout:
        enabled: true
    session:
      enabled: true
```

When I access the exposed `/login`endpoint with the correct parameters via. a `vue.js`frontend or even with `postman`:

```
{
 "username":"admin",
 "password":"admin
}
```

the response has the statuscode `403 Forbidden` but still contains a valid cookie with a `session-id`. Should the returned status code not be `200 OK`? Or do i misunderstand how to use the `security-session`of micronaut?

Comment: Try setting log level `io.micronaut.security` to `TRACE`